# Equivalent Windows API to power shell get-physicaldisk command

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, hard-drive

Configured Storage pool (with Physical disk 1 and Physical 2) in the Windows server and created Virtual disk out of storage pool. After creation of virtual disk, able to see the Physical disk 3(Virtual disk) in VDS service.

Power shell command:  `get-physicaldisk` providing the all the physical disk details including physical disk 1 and physical disk 2.

Is there any Windows API equivalent to  `get-physicaldisk` command exists?
If yes, please suggest me the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [Microsoft WMI - Windows Management Instrumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wmi-start-page) to get info through the [`MSFT_PhysicalDisk` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/stormgmt/msft-physicaldisk).

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33359142/15485 you can find a C sample to start from.