# Calculating hard drive throughput

Tags: c#, .net, hard-drive, throughput

My app creates a 2GB file and needs to select the fastest drive on the system with enough space. I am trying to calculate throughput by creating the file, setting the length, then writing data to it sequentially as follows:

```
FileInfo file = null;
var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
var stats = new List<DriveInfoStatistics>();

foreach (var drive in drives)
{
    do
    {
        file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(drive.RootDirectory.FullName, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D") + ".tmp"));
    }
    while (file.Exists);

    try
    {
        using (var stream = file.Open(FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            var seconds = 10;
            var frameRate = 120F;
            var bytesWritten = 0L;
            var bytesPerPixel = 1;
            var watch = new Stopwatch();
            var videoSize = new Size(1328, 1048);
            var buffer = new byte [(int) (videoSize.Width * videoSize.Height * bytesPerPixel)];

            stream.SetLength((long) (videoSize.Width * videoSize.Height * bytesPerPixel * frameRate * seconds));

            watch.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < frameRate; j++)
                {
                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    bytesWritten += buffer.Length;
                }
            }
            watch.Stop();

            stats.Add(new DriveInfoStatistics(drive, bytesWritten / watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds));
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        file.Refresh();
        if (file.Exists) { try { file.Delete(); } finally { file.Refresh(); } }
    }
}

if (stats.Count == 0)
{
    throw (new Exception("No suitable drives were found."));
}
else
{
    stats.Sort((x, y) => y.DataTransferRate.CompareTo(x.DataTransferRate));

    message
        = "The following drives are suitable candidates (best to worst):"
        + Environment.NewLine
        + Environment.NewLine
        + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, stats.ConvertAll<string>(s => (s.DriveInfo.RootDirectory.FullName.Substring(0, 2).ToUpper() + " " + ConversionUtilities.ToIsuBytesNotation(s.DataTransferRate) + "ps")))
        + Environment.NewLine
        + Environment.NewLine
        + "Test results may vary based on other applications accessing the drives."
        + Environment.NewLine
        + Environment.NewLine
        + "Try the test with the system configured as it would be in production."
        ;

    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

The results I am getting make no sense:

**DESKTOP**

```
D: 4.15 GBps // SSD.
F: 4.09 GBps // HDD (5200 RPM).
E: 4.06 GBps // HDD (7500 RPM).
C: 4.03 GBps // SSD.
H: 2.45 GBps // Ram Disk!!!
```

- First of all, the SSDs and HDDs are too close together.
- Secondly, the speeds are much faster than I would expect.
- Thirdly, the Ram Disk (created with RAMDisk) seems to have the lowest throughput. In practice, the Ram Disk outperforms others by far when writing actual video data.

**LAPTOP**

```
E: 981.24 MBps // Ram Disk.
C: 100.17 MBps // HDD (5200 RPM).
D: 055.94 MBps // HDD (5200 RPM).
```

The results of the same code on my development laptop are more believable.

Is there something wrong with the code above? If not, how would you explain a throughput of 4 GBps for an SSD while the Ram Disk tops out at 2.5 GBps?

I understand there are many factors affecting throughput and that benchmarking software is very sophisticated. However, in my case writing a 2GB video file at 120 frames per second without losing frames is crucial and the above code is supposed to present the user with a quick and dirty recommendation on which drive to use to hold transient video frames. The frames are later post-processed and transcoded into an MP4 video only a few megabytes in size.

Lastly, I have tried the above code alongside `Contig.exe` from `Sysinternals` to ensure a contiguous layout for better HDD performance. However, I did not notice a difference in performance which indicates that the file was not fragmented enough to begin with (upon creation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a program writes data to disk, there happen quite a lot of different things:

First the data is written into a RAM buffer and the operation is acknowledged to the writing program way before the data is transfered to the next stages.

Then data is written to the Harddisk controller which may do its own caching.

Then data is written to the hard-drive which in turn may do its own caching.

It is very complicated to measure the *real* throughput with high level software.

One possibility: Write a very large file, which is expected to be much larger than any chaches in the Operating System / Controler/Hard drive. This gives you a good estimate of *sustained writing rate*.

Comment: I thought it would be simpler than that to get a rough sense of relative speed. It's not the actual speed that matters in my case. I hadn't found a way to determine whether a given disk was an HDD, SSD or Ram Disk. That information would have been enough without the need to perform actual write tests.

Comment: Do remember anything else that could be going on, av, encryption, compression.

Comment: I haven't read much on the matter but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726522/what-is-the-easiest-way-in-c-sharp-to-check-if-hard-disk-is-ssd-without-writing discusses a solution to determine if a disk is ssd or hdd.

Comment: @BugFinder: I have already excluded all forms of transcoding, compression, on-the-fly processing in favour of sequential-write speed. We simply grab raw data from the camera hardware buffer and write it directly in binary format without any conversion.

Comment: @prettyvoid: Thanks. It seems the method in the linked question is not fool proof but it's the closest I can get to providing a reasonable recommendation. I still have no idea if I'm goofing up with my own write tests though (the code included with the question).